# Ruby on Rails 6: Why doesn't receive(data) method work in ActionCable of my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I'm working on a real time chat application in Rails 6 with Windows OS, and my ActionCable has an issue.

The development adapter doesn't work at all(I guess), neither async, neither Redis. I tried everything but I am really stuck at this point :(.

I have a channel called 'room', with the following coding on it's back-end side (app/channels/room_channel.rb):

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    reject unless params[:room_id]

    room = Room.find params[:room_id].to_i
    stream_for room
end

def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed 
end
end
```

And in its front-end side: (app/javascript/room_channel.js):

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

let url = window.location.href;
let room_id = parseInt(url.substring(url.search("rooms/") + 6) );

if (url.indexOf("rooms/") != -1) {

console.log('Subscribed to room', room_id);

consumer.subscriptions.create({ "channel": "RoomChannel", "room_id": room_id }, {
  connected() {
    console.log('connected')
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log('data received successfully')
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
}
```

When I run the server I am able to subscribe and connect to the channel, but the channel cannot receive any incoming data (in my case, messages). I know it because it doesn't output the console message ('data received successfully') when I create a new message in the room.

**Other important information is** when my co-worker runs this application with his computer with the same coding everywhere, he can receive data (he gets the 'data received successfully' output when he sends a message to the room). And as I said, we have the same exact coding everywhere!

So I am sure about the fact that it is not the code's fault, the problem is with my computer or I don't know.

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks for reading and waiting for the helpful people's answers! :)

Comment: check if your connection is being disconnected for some reason. Do a console log in the `disconnected` method in the `room_channel.js` file